# "browsing" another website from asp.net

Tags: asp.net

as part of an integration (not soap, not really rest). i need to hit another website with a series of well formatted url's

the 1st one in the series has to be a login url (http://server.com/login.php?u=xxx&p=yyyy

this creates the serverside session and authenticates me. then using the same session i can call any one of the next few urls

e.g. http://server.com/getall.php?id=123  http://server.com/findbyname.php?name=bob  etc etc

i need to keep one session open the whole time, and be able to strip the responses out of each.....

I can either do this server side (on a post back), or clientside with javascript (note - target server is on a different domain from my asp.net server)

Thanks

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: apologies. prettu much how to go about doing this from my asp.net server. my gut tells me to use an httpwebrequest, but how can i keep the same session alive by reusing the httpwebrequest over and over again. almost as if i were manually using the same webbrowser over and over. if i use a 2nd httpwebrequest, the php server sees me as a new session (i.e. as if i closed my web browser if in a manual simulation)